# User Exit EXIT_SAPLBARM_003

Tags: hook, abap, sap-erp

I am trying to use User Exit EXIT_SAPLBARM_003 however I cannot seem to get it activated.

In CMOD I created a project and added XMRM0001 as the Enhancement Assignment, by default the only components that I see is EXIT_SAPLBARM_001 and EXIT_SAPLBARM_003, but EXIT_SAPLBARM_002 and EXIT_SAPLBARM_004 are missing.

**link to image broken** [image: CMOD Enhancements]

I realize in the picture the User Exit is not active, but that's because I am trying to add EXIT_SAPLBARM_003.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated as always.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the User Exit on SMOD and add the Function Module.

Att.